# Resolve URL to AWS Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, ip, resolve

I have a domain that I own. I will say is example.com. I added SSO.example.com as a Type A record on GoDaddy with a value of 37.89.245.2(example).

The IP address is a elastic IP on a Windows AWS server.

I can ping the IP address but I can't ping the URL. Do I need to do something with the IP address on the AWS Windows server to be able to ping the URL?

This is pretty much one of my first web based projects so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "Ping the URL" makes no sense - are you hitting it with a browser or the "curl" command or what?

Comment: What I mean is using command line typing "ping sso.example.com"

Comment: And the DNS name resolves to an IP? Try it out at https://mxtoolbox.com/dnscheck.aspx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was jumping the gun a bit and the new NameServers I was using had not replicated completely yet. After replication completed everything was able to be pinged successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Ping is not a reliable test method in AWS because most security groups do not permit inbound ICMP protocol, which is used by Ping. So, if you really want to test connectivity, do it on a port that you actually need your application to support, such as HTTP (80) or trying an SSH/RDP connection.

Another common use for a Ping is to resolve the domain name to an IP address, since it displays the result on-screen. This can be a good way to check that your Amazon Route 53 configuration is correct. (Same as a dnslookup.)

Comment: Except that *"I can ping the IP address,"* so pinging by name should also work in this case.